# "Class 'Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies' not found" LARAVEL

Tags: laravel

```
Class 'Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies' not found
```

[image]

Comment: Did you install it? `composer require fideloper/proxy`

Comment: @LupithaYañezC. OK. As a general rule, you're going to have to install stuff before you can use it. :-/

Comment: @ceejayoz TrustProxies is included by default on Laravel 5.5+ installations: https://laravel-news.com/trusted-proxy

Comment: i installed laravel 5.7 a few minutes ago and for some reason i have the same issue...

Comment: You might need to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71117387/3347337) answer if you are upgrading to Laravel 9.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
composer require fideloper/proxy
```

Answer (score 10):

in Laravel v10, as @Sujata Jadhav wrote,
I remove fideloper/proxy
and in `app/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.php`,
I changed :

```
use Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies as Middleware;
// […]
protected $headers = Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL;
```

with

```
use Illuminate\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies as Middleware;
// […] 
protected $headers =
    Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_FOR |
    Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_HOST |
    Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PORT |
    Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PROTO; // I removed AWS_ELB line as I don't need it
```

as we can see at doc pages :

- https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/upgrade#the-assert-deleted-method
- https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/requests#configuring-trusted-proxies

Answer (score 9):

If you faced the error after upgrading laravel 8 to 9 or 10 we don't need the Trustproxies package from the composer. You can simply remove by composer remove fideloper/proxy and update your packages by composer update command. it's properly mentioned in the laravel 9 upgrade guide. laravel.com/docs/9.x/upgrade#the-assert-deleted-method