# Class 'Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies' not found

Tags: laravel, proxy

I have used a library Lavacharts.
But when after downloading through Composer, I ran my project it gave me error.

> Class 'Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies' not found

[image: Here is the link to image]

Comment: can u run this command `composer dump-autoload` and `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: @JigneshJoisar Nothing happened.... :(

Comment: check in composer.json `"fideloper/proxy"` package in there if not then add

Comment: here it is

"require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "jimmyjs/laravel-report-generator": "^1.0",

Comment: check in actual file is there or not?

Comment: No the actual file is not there

Comment: and composer require fideloper/proxy
is also not working

Comment: first remove and then again add

Comment: how to remove?Because file is not there

Comment: I also removed from composer.json and then added again after running command but  this error is happening.

Comment: see this link it will helpful to u https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23126562/how-to-remove-a-package-from-laravel-using-composer

Comment: Not Working :(
I tried

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is the same as the following [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47193349/class-fideloper-proxy-trustproxies-not-found-laravel/47201641)
and should be solved by accepted answer their

```
composer require fideloper/proxy
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to just run this : composer require fideloper/proxy then composer dump-autoload

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).