# Error: While updating laravel 8 to 9. Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-9

> Nothing to install, update or remove
> Generating optimized autoload files
> Class App\Helpers\Helper located in C:/wamp64/www/vuexylaravel/app\Helpers\helpers.php does not comply
> with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
> > Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> > @php artisan package:discover --ansi

```
   Error 

  Undefined constant Illuminate\Http\Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL
  at C:\wamp64\www\vuexylaravel\vendor\fideloper\proxy\config\trustedproxy.php:48
     44▕      * - 'HEADER_X_FORWARDED_AWS_ELB' (If you are using AWS Elastic Load Balancer)
     45▕      *
     46▕      * @link https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment/proxies.html
     47▕      */
  ➜  48▕     'headers' => Illuminate\Http\Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL,
     49▕
     50▕ ];
     51▕

  1   C:\wamp64\www\vuexylaravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider.php:138
      require()

  2   C:\wamp64\www\vuexylaravel\vendor\fideloper\proxy\src\TrustedProxyServiceProvider.php:28
      Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider::mergeConfigFrom("C:\wamp64\www\vuexylaravel\vendor\fideloper\proxy\config\trustedproxy.php", "trustedproxy")
Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

***If you are upgrading your Laravel 8 project to Laravel 9 by importing your existing application code into a totally new Laravel 9 application skeleton, you may need to update your application's "trusted proxy" middleware.***

Within your `app/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.php` file, update:

`use Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies as Middleware`

to

`use Illuminate\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies as Middleware`

Next, within `app/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.php`, you should update the `$headers` property definition:

// Before...

```
protected $headers = Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL;
```

// After...

```
protected $headers =
    Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_FOR |
    Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_HOST |
    Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PORT |
    Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PROTO |
    Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_AWS_ELB;
```

Then run `composer update`

**Make sure you are using PHP 8.0**

Comment: I also had to remove the file config/trustedproxy.php in my own case

Answer (score 94):

The colleague with the answer above is, in principle, right. Only he forgot to mention that after all the changes in the file, you need to delete the package `fideloper/proxy`:

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/upgrade

> ### Trusted Proxies
>
> ##### Likelihood Of Impact: Low
>
> If you are upgrading your Laravel 8 project to Laravel 9 by importing your existing application code into a totally new Laravel 9 application skeleton, you may need to update your application's "trusted proxy" middleware.
>
> Within your `app/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.php` file, update `use Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies as Middleware` to `use Illuminate\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies as Middleware`.
>
> Next, within `app/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.php`, you should update the `$headers` property definition:
>
> ```
> // Before...
> protected $headers = Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL;
>
> // After...
> protected $headers =
>    Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_FOR |
>    Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_HOST |
>    Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PORT |
>    Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PROTO |
>    Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_AWS_ELB;
> ```
>
> **Finally, you can remove the `fideloper/proxy` Composer dependency from your application**:
>
> `composer remove fideloper/proxy`

Comment: Thx alot but right after that i got `Target class [Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors] does not exist.` sorry i just had to remove `\Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,` from app/Http/Kernel.php : ` protected $middleware = [

Comment: @Николай Thanks alot. That spot on was the issue for me.

Comment: I also had to remove the file config/trustedproxy.php in my own case

Answer (score 7):

If the above answer does not work for you and you are getting the same error, execute one more line for removing the fideloper/proxy from composer.json.

```
// Before...
protected $headers = Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL;
 
// After...
protected $headers =
    Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_FOR |
    Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_HOST |
    Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PORT |
    Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PROTO |
    Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_AWS_ELB;
```

This will remove the proxy from the composer.json and the exception will be gone.

```
composer remove fideloper/proxy
```

it's properly mentioned in the laravel 9 upgrade guide.
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/upgrade#the-assert-deleted-method

Comment: when i run ```composer remove fideloper/proxy``` , get this new bug: **Undefined array key "format"** , do you know how to fix it ?

Comment: Thanks. It's worked. The approved answer didn't help, cause I have no TrustProxies.php. I don't know why, I just didn't have that middleware.

Answer (score 2):

Basically all above anwser are telling the same thing, Laravel docs are correct, simply follow instructions.

But is you still have the same error (like I did), delete file "config/trustedproxy.php". This fixs the error.

Comment: Was still getting the same error after laravel docs, but removed "config/trustedproxy.php" fixes the error

Answer (score 1):

If you are upgrading your Laravel 8 project to Laravel 9 by importing your existing application code into a totally new Laravel 9 application skeleton, I tried this solution below.

a) I fixed it by deleting "config/trustedproxy.php". I did not have the TrustProxies middleware on the directory at app\Http\Middleware on my side

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: No sure why I had this file too (can't find it on official github repo), but deleting it solved my problem. Thx !

Comment: It's right here https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/9.x/app/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.php

Answer (score 1):

If you are upgrading your Laravel 8 project to Laravel 9 by importing your existing application code into a totally new Laravel 9 application skeleton, you may need to update your application's "trusted proxy" middleware.

Within your app/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.php file, update use Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies as Middleware to use Illuminate\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies as Middleware.

Next, within app/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.php, you should update the $headers property definition:

```
// Before...
protected $headers = Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL;
 
// After...
protected $headers =
    Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_FOR |
    Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_HOST |
    Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PORT |
    Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PROTO |
    Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_AWS_ELB;
```

Finally, you can remove the fideloper/proxy Composer dependency from your application:

composer remove fideloper/proxy

Answer (score 0):

**Two things I did after following the laravel upgrade doc which worked for me:**

1. Manually go into composer.json and remove the fideloper/proxy

Run composer update. If you still get the issue. Follow next:

2. Check if this file **TrustProxies.php** is present  located at vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies.php if Not you can copy from old one.

Answer (score -1):

you need to delete file "config/trustedproxy.php"

After run composer update

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).